# How to use an opacity mask in a material in Blender Cycles?

Tags: transparency

Following a tutorial about creating a stylised tree, I ran into a problem. The tutorial is for Maya instead of Blender and Substance Designer. I modelled on Blender.

In the tutorial for Maya they manage to insert the basic color map and the opacity mask well, which I can't do in Blender. I have attached images with the problem. I tried to search on the net but I can't achieve showing only the leaves and the branches as it happens in the tutorial.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some wrong inputs in your image
basic mask setup in blender:

[image]

Comment: I did it anyway but thanks for the help. does it involve anything to invert transparent nodes and base color?

Comment: there is a color invert node in the color tab

Answer (score 0):

I solved, sorry for the trouble. I fiddled a bit though, I solved it with a lot of luck xD
[image]