# Is it possible to mask parts of a model to let them always appear top of other objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, masking, 2d, toon-shading, mmd-tools

I recently work on toon shader in Blender cycles and EEVEE and quite curious how the game achieves this effect.

What I want to do is to somehow "see through" the hair and when the hair cover the eyebrows and eyes, the outline of the eyebrow and eyes are still visible.

As you can see the pic below:

[image]

I think they make this effect by using a mask texture as the pic shown below, which named in "HET" and I don't know what it means actually. However, this texture is surely the map I need to figure out and I totally got no clue of which nodes set up I should use!

[image]
[image]

[Blend File](https://mega.nz/file/Ck1SHQrK#67e3tgGLzOcjlbhS93ACGP8JoqH8fJClNVdR_gL-ZnE).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an opacity mask in a material in Blender Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149031/how-to-use-an-opacity-mask-in-a-material-in-blender-cycles)

Comment: These "HET" images are masks. But I don't know how you could use them. The problem is that the masks are for the face and eyes but you need to make the hair transparent else you get something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHygt.jpg Basically, you want to make the dark areas of the face shine through the hair but cover the skin with the hair strands.

Answer (score 1):

In game engines you could use shaders with stencil buffers or depth information to achieve this. You could use a similar technique of leveraging depth information to do this in compositing.

Here's my scene:
[image]

I created two view layers, one for the character and one for the hair. Here's one of them:
[image]

Then I rendered (including Z pass) and created masks based on the two depth images.
I've had two quick attempts at this:
[image]

(NOTE: the subtract is a quick hack. should probably use min/max and then add/sub)
Then I realized I should've rendered with transparent background and simplified it:
[image]

I set a black background for the base image because blender is annoying with merging colors when alphas are involved. Maybe someone else could improve upon that.